# How do I pass a list of df col names to a purrr::map formula?

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to pass a list of col names to a purrr::map formula. 
Here is a reprex of my issue:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(purrr)
    #Make a toy df of w vars of 2 levels
    cars <- mtcars %>%
    select(mpg, cyl, carb) %>% 
    filter(cyl == 4 | cyl == 6,
           carb == 2 | carb == 4)

    #normal fn call, works fine
    t.test(mpg ~ cyl, data = cars)
    t.test(mpg ~ carb, data = cars)

    Welch Two Sample t-test
    data:  mpg by cyl
    t = 3.5371, df = 7.0689, p-value = 0.009356

    Welch Two Sample t-test
    data:  mpg by carb
    t = 3.5371, df = 7.0689, p-value = 0.009356

    #Make list of cols 
    list_vars <- names(cars[,-1])
    list_vars
    [1] "cyl"  "carb"

    #Attempt map with formula fn call
    map(list_vars, ~ t.test(mpg ~ .x, data = cars))

    #Results in this error
    Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg ~ .x, data = cars) : 
    variable lengths differ (found for '.x')
```

I know there is an entire new world of "quosure" programing with dplyr 0.7, but this seems like something that would be fairly common and predate that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can build the formula via `paste` with `formula`: `map(list_vars, ~t.test(formula(paste("mpg ~", .x)), data = cars))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the above, but it's best not to deal with non-standard evaluation when working with `purrr` if you can. Here is another approach:

```
list_vars %>% 
  map(~ t.test(cars[[.x]], cars$mpg))
```

This leverages the default S3 method of `t.test` instead of the S3 method for class `formula`. So what's happening is you are feeding in vectors as the first two arguments instead of feeding in a dataframe and telling `t.test` where to look.

Comment: Thank you for both the answer and explanation, very helpful to have something that works and start to understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: While this is a way around the formula issue, this use of `t.test` returns tests of, e.g., mean mpg vs mean cylinder instead of testing mean mpg among the two different cyinder categories.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
map(list_vars, ~ t.test(mpg ~ col, data = cars %>% rename_("col" = .x)))
```